# print all leaves in BST: why there should be two base cases?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm looking at the solution of BST problem, printing all leaves in BST as below:

```
def printLeaf(root):
  if not root: # why this line of code is needed if the if statement below returns as base case?
    return
  if not root.left and not root.right:
    print(root.val)
    return
  printLeaf(root.left)
  printLeaf(root.right)
```

I initially wrote my code without the first base case returning at null value of root. But it thrown an error. In my head, it shouldn't go below leaf since I returned after printing the node but it wasn't like that since it went down to null stack and threw NoneType exception.
Adding the first line of the function works but still don't get it why I need that line of code. Can someone kindly explain why?

Code below not stopping recursion, still going down to null node

```
if not root.left and not root.right:
    print(root.val)
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional branch is triggered only when a node in question has neither `left` nor `right` child. If only one child is present like in the 2 cases below, nothing prevents you from trying to process an empty node, i.e. `None`:

```
    Node with       |         Node with
right child only    |      left child only
                    |
    Node(1)         |        Node(2)
    /    \          |         /   \
   /      \         |        /     \
 None   Node(2)     |    Node(1)   None
```

To properly handle these cases you either need to check the child nodes before recursing further, e.g.

```
def print_leaves(node):
   if node.left is None and node.right is None:
       print(node.value)
   if node.left is not None:
       print_leaves(node.left)
   if node.right is not None:
       print_leaves(node.right)
```

(which is still technically wrong, since you assume that the initial argument is never `None`). Or you always check the argument for `None` first like you already are doing.

Comment: So in other words, my code doesn't stop proceeding None node where there isn't `left` or `right` attribute therefore it goes down below leaf, whereas your code controls this to guarantee the only node to be executed in the call stack. Am I correct?

Comment: The problem with your code is that when a node has **only 1 child** you still recurse **both** into left and right branches. Look at the examples I've provided: the topmost node has children so you do not stop the execution there and recurse further down instead, but one of those recursive calls will be equivalent to `printLeaf(None)`, and trying to access `None.left` during your is-this-a-leaf check results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because `root.left` and `root.right` in the last two lines could be None.